# Events not triggered in XLForms

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, xlform

I'm using `XLForms` to build an iOS app. I am having a problem with getting action events. I've tried both `block` and `formSelector` but I'm not getting the events.

**Here is my code:**

```
 XLFormRowDescriptor * buttonRow = [XLFormRowDescriptor formRowDescriptorWithTag:@"button" rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeButton title:@"Button"];
 [buttonRow.cellConfig setObject:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey:@"textLabel.textColor"];
 buttonRow.action.formSelector = @selector(didTouchURLButton:);
 [section addFormRow:buttonRow];
```

I did compile/run the sample app with no problems. I can't figure out what the difference is. I'm not using *Cocoa Pods* but inserted the code into the project.

It almost seems like the delegate isn't being set correctly but even when I make the call `self.form.delegate = self`, I still don't get the events.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you implementing the delegate in .h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was I had another method that was picking up the event first:

```
 -(void)didTouchButton:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)sender
{
     [self deselectFormRow:sender];
}
```